# Why does "forgetive" mean "creative", not "easy to forget things"?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

As the title says. It surprised me when I found this [online dictionary entry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/forgetive) at the time I tried to express "easy to forget things" and "forgetive" appeared in my mind.

What is the history or background of this word? Also, what adjective means "easy to forget things" in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*forge* + tive

probably from *forge* + -tive (as in inventive)  First Known Use: *1597*

Forge: form or create with concerted effort.

> The politician's recent actions are an effort to forge a relationship with undecided voters.

Easily forgotten: [forgettable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forgettable) easily forgotten, esp. through being uninteresting or mediocre.

> It was an extremely forgettable performance.

someone who forgets: [forgetful](https://www.google.com/search?q=forgetful&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a): apt or likely not to remember.

> I'm a bit forgetful these days

also: absentminded

Comment: Thanks, So SourceForge means creating source code?

Comment: @Earth Engine: It's just a website name, so there's a limit to how far you can take the idea that it "means" anything. But most likely *Sourceforge* is so-named because of the close association between the *noun* "forge" (where a blacksmith works) and "workshop". [Here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=forge+workshop&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) are plenty of results from Google showing how often the two words are used in proximity.

Answer (score 4):

From OED...

> **forgetive** - a Shakespearian word, of uncertain formation and meaning. Commonly taken as a derivative of *forge*, and hence used by writers of the 19th c. for: Apt at ‘forging’, inventive, creative.
>
> **forge** - to make, fashion, frame, or construct (any material thing); = *fabricate*

Someone who often forgets things is *forgetful* (or *absent-minded*), and someone who is easy to forget is *forgettable*.